# Pygame Load Image

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, pygame

So what I am doing is trying to create a board game in pygame and what I have so far is the code to load an image of the board to draw to the screen however I am experiencing some difficulties when it is coming to opening the image through pygame. Just if you're curious this is the path to the image I am trying to load. `/home/kody/Coding/Python/Test/MonopolyPygame/MonopolyLib/board.bmp`

So I have a class that I use to load the image called IMAGE and in it I have an init method.

```
class IMAGE
    __init__(self):
    self.self.board = pygame.image.load("board.bmp")
IMAGE()
```

If I just run this little program alone it runs fine, however when I run it with my `Main` class it seems to fail.

So I have the main.py in a folder called BoardPygame. Then I have a folder within BoardPygame called BoardLib. Within the file BoardLib I have a python file called **init**.py making BoardLib a library, and then I have another python file called images .py which only contains the class `IMAGE`, also within this file I have a bmp called board.bmp

In my file `main.py` I have a class which is called Main. And then from that I have the way I get to the images.py in order to load the images, or at least attempt to do so.

```
import BoardLib
from BoardLib import *

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Images = images.IMAGE()
```

However whenever I run the program just using the main.py file it always comes up with the error

```
File "/home/kody/Coding/Python/Test/MonopolyPygame/MonopolyLib/images.py", line 8, in __init__
self.board = pygame.image.load("board.bmp")
pygame.error: Couldn't open board.bmp
```

Any reason why this may be coming up with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is the current working directory when each IMAGE is constructed?

Comment: after the exception, check the directory you are in idle. Assign the relative folder from that directory which will point at folder where you store your images. Prepend that directory before every image you want to load

Comment: @tepples that could very well be the reason why, i don't think the @OP meant to include `self.self`

Answer (score 1):

```
class IMAGE
    __init__(self):
    self.self.board = pygame.image.load("board.bmp")
IMAGE()
```

in this code try removing the double self, like this

```
class IMAGE
    __init__(self):
    self.board = pygame.image.load("board.bmp")
IMAGE()
```

and also, in the main , try this :

```
import BoardLib
from BoardLib import *

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Images = IMAGE().board
```

Hope this helps.